# default language in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

i want my shop be just in one language for example in Hindi.i install new language and set it as default language and remove language block from front end of my shop.but when the shop opens still the English is the default language and i have to switch to Hindi.

how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have changed your site default language to be something else than English, then you have to go to Localization > Language and there, make sure your desired language, in this case Hindi, is enabled. Once done, you can disable English.

If you just delete language block from the front office, that does not change the language - just removes the possibility for the user to change the language.

Answer (score 0):

is it on all computers/browsers?

maybe that you have some cookies saved in your browser that cause to load english for you, but others will open in Hindi...

you you really want only one language, maybe disable all the others